# Year comparison in PHP

Tags: php, date, if-statement, comparison

```
        if($_POST['syear']){
            $compy = strtotime($_POST['syear']);
            if(date("Y") <= date("Y", $compy)){
                //success
                $startdate = $_POST['syear'];
            }
            else{
                $error = 6;
            }
        }
```

I have created the above code and have no idea where I have gone wrong. I am posting a string from a form with a number in it and want to compare it to the current year. If the number is equal to or less than the current year it is supposed to be a success. It is always a success even if the number is larger than the current year. Do I need to convert some strings to ints or have I missed something entirely.

Comment: `var_dump($_POST['syear'], $compy);` --- **ALWAYS** check what you **ACTUALLY** have in variables, don't program with eyes closed

Comment: string(4) "2013" int(1342638780) so what do i need to set the strtotime to to get a year in a readable format?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PHP handle string comparison very well, did you try this directly ? (and changing the comparison order to >=)

```
if($_POST['syear']){
    if(date("Y") >= $_POST['syear']){
        $startdate = $_POST['syear'];
    }else{
        $error = 6;
    }
}
```

Comment: thankyou, I think I tried it but with the comparison the other way and I had the same result, your answer worked, thankyou

Answer (score 1):

You cannot convert simply a year to time. Using your example as is, you need to have a string of yyyy/mm/dd format to use strtotime. If you are really just checking year, you can use January 1st as a check date.

```
 $compy = strtotime($_POST['syear'] . '-01-01' );
```

Comment: ok thanks. checking a year to set an auto copyright footer date.

Comment: Oops, I just noticed i used a "/" when I should have used a "-" for the date separator.

Answer (score 0):

You can compare integers or strings the same way. If you want to be sure about the type comparison you can always cast the variable but in this case it's pointless.
2012 is inferior to 2013. "2012" is inferior to "2013". date( 'Y' ) returns a 4 characters string you can compare with your $_POST['syear'] if it's a 4 character string. Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

You could try

```
if(time() <= $compy){
```

since your already doing `strtotime()` on whatever compy is originally. This way your working with 2 unix timestamps and comparing them that way.

Comment: Not an answer. There is no difference between `date("Y", time())` and `date("Y")`

Comment: i think your answer is actually going to work judging by the sounds of it, the other one is still small number vs timestamp after additions to strtotime

Comment: zerkms is refering to my original answer, and likely downvoted it in the process.. I have since edited it, this should work in concept pending on what your doing overall, but if your initally converting it to a unix timestamp with strtotime, then comparing it to another timestamp is your best choice even when adding/subtracting time from it so long as the timestamp remains valid and doesnt go out of date so to speak

Comment: well here is 2013 and current time() --- int(1342638780) 1342649328

Comment: That should be fine, by my statement of out of date in a matter of speaking is, that there is a certain allowed range betweeen what is a valid timestamp and whats not.. I don't remember what it is exactly off the top of my head though